Can't suppress NotOpenSSLWarning in Python Script
I can't suppress the following error:
 NotOpenSSLWarning: urllib3 v2 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with 'LibreSSL 2.8.3'. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/3020
  warnings.warn(

The code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_page_soup(url):
    import warnings
    from urllib3.exceptions import NotOpenSSLWarning

    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=NotOpenSSLWarning)
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

